# Getting dates outside of range I specify

Tags: sql, reporting-services, plsql

I have a report that I am trying to fix with SSRS because when you run it for a specific range say one month of year. It will give you all previous years too even if its outside of parameter bounds.

```
SELECT
     to_char(app.RECEIVED_DATE, 'mm-dd-yyyy') AS received_date
      , res.RESIDENCETYPE_NAME || ' - ' || act.ACTIONTYPE_NAME type
      , sts.APPLSTSTYPE_NAME AS Status
      , COUNT(*) AS Total_Count
      FROM
      ODILIC_ADMIN.LICENSEAPPL app
      , ODILIC_ADMIN.LICENSEDEF def
      , ODILIC_ADMIN.ACTIONTYPE act
      , ODILIC_ADMIN.APPLSOURCE src
      , ODILIC_ADMIN.RESIDENCETYPE res
      , ODILIC_ADMIN.LICENSETYPE ltype
      , ODILIC_ADMIN.LICENSINGENTITYTYPE etype
      , ODILIC_ADMIN.APPLSTSTYPE sts
      WHERE        app.LICENSEDEF_ID = def.LICENSEDEF_ID
      AND app.ACTIONTYPE_ID = act.ACTIONTYPE_ID
      AND app.APPLSOURCE_ID = src.APPLSOURCE_ID
      AND def.RESIDENCETYPE_ID = res.RESIDENCETYPE_ID
      AND def.LICENSETYPE_ID = ltype.LICENSETYPE_ID
      AND def.LICENSINGENTITYTYPE_ID = etype.LICENSINGENTITYTYPE_ID
      AND app.APPLSTSTYPE_ID = sts.APPLSTSTYPE_ID
      AND (app.RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN  '01-JUN-2013' AND '30-JUN-2013')
        and sts.APPLSTSTYPE_NAME in ('Completed')
      GROUP BY
      to_char(app.RECEIVED_DATE, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
      , res.RESIDENCETYPE_NAME
      , act.ACTIONTYPE_NAME
      , sts.APPLSTSTYPE_NAME
      order by 1
```

So this query will filter between jun 1  and jun 30 of this year. When I run it in plsql it works fine but as soon as I put it into ssrs it will give me june counts for 2012 and 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line: AND (app.RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN  '01-JUN-2013' AND '30-JUN-2013')

I would be setting up parameters in SSRS directly to handle this as this may handle the translation of types more expicitly to specify (DateTime) as the parameter type and then changing the line to be:

AND (app.RECEIVED_DATE BETWEEN @Start AND @End)

I have not played with plsql with SSRS but I have seen translation of types problems with dealing with WCF and other channels.  My usual attempt is to first specify a parameter to pass into the query execution and see if there is still an issue.

Comment: That line is specifically for plsql to check that the data is right. In ssrs this line is: (to_char(app.RECEIVED_DATE,'mm/dd/YYYY') BETWEEN  to_char(:start_date,'mm/dd/YYYY') AND to_char(:end_date,'mm/dd/YYYY'))

Comment: For whatever reason it only looks at month and date but not year.

Comment: If you are converting something to char that could be an issue as DateTime can have many interpretations through SSRS.  I thought you were just doing a cast in the 'Select' statement but not the where clause?

Comment: I found a workaround by saying AND (app.RECEIVED_DATE) > (:start_date)

Comment: I dont understand though still why the between statement does not work with the year.

Comment: there was a cast to char in the where clause at first but I took it out. A contractor wrote this and I am just cleaning up the mess.

Comment: Ahhh contractor messes, good stuff.  I am guessing it is CONVERTING to char and then evaulating what it believes to be between which once converted is no longer a date range.